# Where can I download oracle 10g 64 bit client for linux?

Tags: oracle10g

Guys!

I know oracle 10g download link does not exist in Oracle official site.

But I need one.

Oracle 10g 64-bit client for linux!

I founded some sites for window client, but not for Linux...

Someone knows where can I download oracle 10g 64 bit client for linux?

Comment: You can only get the full client via a support contract; but the instant client [is still available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html).

Comment: Thank you for comment. So where can I get even instant client ?

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Comment: Thank you Alex Poole! Ofcourse it's not full client, but I got something to say to my boss :) . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Officially nowhere:
"Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download. The software is available as a media or FTP request for those customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any edition. To request access to these releases, follow the instructions in Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or Download URL for Software Media) from My Oracle Support. NOTE: for Oracle Database 10.2, you should request 10.2.0.1 even if you want to install a later patch set. Once you install 10.2.0.1 you can then apply any 10.2 patch set. Similarly, for 11.1 request 11.1.0.6 which must be applied before installing 11.1.0.7. Patch sets can be downloaded from the Patches and Updates tab on My Oracle Support."